# Ask Ubuntu Unicorn

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

Is this unicorn on Ask Ubuntu an April Fools' Day joke?

[image]

Comment: [How can I get the April Fool's joke to appear?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127701)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely. It looks like a reincarnation of [Clippy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clippy).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127698/its-clip-cloppy

Comment: Just wanted to mention I'm a huge Clippy fan...can we make this feature permanent?